# How to apply conditional aggreation to series?

Tags: python, pandas

To apply an aggregation on a groupby for a single column is:

```
df.groupby('column_name1')['column_name2'].agg(sum)
```

I have data which I would like to apply sum() on column2 if column1 contains value A, and count() if the value is B.

What is the syntax to accomplish this?

I was trying to write a for-loop with if-statement, but I was hoping there is a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below two lines:

```
df[df['column_name1'].str.contains('A')]=df[df['column_name1'].str.contains('A')].groupby('column_name1')['column_name2'].agg(sum)
df[df['column_name1'].str.contains('B')]=df[df['column_name1'].str.contains('B')].groupby('column_name1')['column_name2'].agg('count')
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can combine this into 1 operation to save the results into the same df?

Comment: @BenCWang They already are, see `print(df)`, it returns the expected dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function for this(obviously you can customize it the way you want):

```
def my_func(row):
    b = row[row.column_name1.str.contains('A')].column_name2.sum()
    c = row[row.column_name1.str.contains('B')].column_name2.count()
    return pd.Series({'Sum':b, 'Count':c})

df.groupby('column_name1').apply(my_func).reset_index()

    column_name1    Sum Count
0   A               8   0
1   B               0   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_name1': ['A','A','A','A1','B','B1','C'],
    'column_name2': np.arange(1, 8)
})
print (df)
  column_name1  column_name2
0            A             1
1            A             2
2            A             3
3           A1             4
4            B             5
5           B1             6
6            C             7

def f(x):
    if x.column_name1.str.contains('A').any():
        return x['column_name2'].sum()
    elif x.column_name1.str.contains('B').any():
        return x['column_name2'].count()
    else:
        return 0

df = df.groupby('column_name1').apply(f).reset_index(name='new')
print (df)
  column_name1  new
0            A    6
1           A1    4
2            B    1
3           B1    1
4            C    0
```